# conflict between scroll and zoom Textview

Tags: android, textview, pinchzoom

I get some problem with a Textview. I've written this code for my app. I would like to be able to do a pinch to zoom and scroll the Textview if necessary. I wrote the code for the pinch to zoom and it works correctly but if I insert the code for the scroll of the textview it doesn't work, but the scroll works correctly. If I delete the scroll code I'm able to do the pinch to zoom, but I can't scroll it, if the text is too long for the page.
What's wrong with my code?

layout code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_testo_canzone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

main code:

```
tv_testo_canzone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_testo_canzone);
        tv_titolo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_titolo_canz);
        tv_artista = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_artista_canz);

        tv_testo_canzone.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
linearLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_canzone);

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(nomeTxt)));

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(mLine);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                }
            }

            tv_testo_canzone.setText((CharSequence) text);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with the code, the think its when you use ScrollView all the child views dont receive gestures because they all are handled by the parent ScrollView

Comment: I'm not using a scrollview. it's a Textview with a scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

```
    description.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
            Log.d("Scroll", "1-pointer touch");
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

        }
        if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
            Log.d("Zoom", "2-pointer touch");
            int action = event.getAction();
            int mainaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            if (mainaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                mBaseDist = getDistance(event);
                mBaseRatio = mRatio;
            } else {
                float scale = (getDistance(event) - mBaseDist) / STEP;
                float factor = (float) Math.pow(2, scale);
                mRatio = Math.min(1024.0f, Math.max(0.1f, mBaseRatio * factor));
                description.setTextSize(mRatio + 15);
            }
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        }
        return true;
    });

}

private int getDistance(MotionEvent event) {
    int dx = (int) (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    int dy = (int) (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    return (int) (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
}
```

Comment: Please post more than just code as an answer. Explain what you are doing, and how it solves the question.